# Receiving an error on VBA code for calculate between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I'm writing VBA code to calculate PnL, between two excel workbooks, one wb(wb.Position) has the Asset name, Beginning  and Ending positions(A1,A2,A3), the second(wb.Price)as same Asset(fx) name, Beginning and Ending PricePrice, Cells A1,A2,A3). I'm using a loop to run through each asset by row, and vlookup to pull in the prices from the Wb.Price, calculating within the loop, aggregating the totals and outputting the total PnL and the % on the wb.Position in cells F7 and G7.

UPDATED: I have applied the changes that have been suggested with some updates in the code still receiving a Compile Error:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PnL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim PnLUSDT, PnLUSDT_percent As Range
Dim Asset As String
Dim BegPos, EndPos, startprice, endprice, unreal_PnL, Real_PnL as Long 
Dim PriceDelta, PnLtotal_USDT, PnLtotal, AssetValue as Long 
Dim AssetValue_USDT, TotalAssetValue, PnlPercent As Long
Dim row As Integer
Dim wbPosition As Range
Dim wbPrice As Range
Dim wbPrice As Workbook
Dim wsPrice As Worksheet

Set wbPosition = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPosition = wbPosition.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:G")
Set wbPrice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Excel Exercise\Excel         
Exercise 2 of 2.xlsx")
Set wsPrice = wbPrice.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C")

row = 2               '<--position sheet has heads, starting with data
TotalAssetValue = 0   '<--aggregate of Asset Value in loop
PnLtotal_USDT = 0     '<--aggregrate of Profit & Loss in loop

With wsPosition       
    While .Cells(row, 1) <> ""

        Asset = .Cells(row, 1)        '<--security name
       'Debug.Print "Asset: ", Asset
        BegPos = .Cells(row, 2)       '<--start position in ws.Position
        EndPos = .Cells(row, 3)       '<--end position in ws.Positon

       With wsPrice
           startprice = Application.VLookup(Asset, wsPrice, 2, 0)   '<--start price in ws.Price
           endprice = Application.VLookup(Asset, wsPrice, 3, 0)     '<--end price in ws.Price
   
               If startprice = endprice Then
                   PriceDelta = endprice     'Price change cannot be 0 for calc purposes
               Else
                   PriceDelta = startprice - endprice
               End If
    

        unreal_PnL = EndPos * PriceDelta    '<--calcing unrealized P&L
        Real_PnL = (BegPos - EndPos) * endprice   '<--calcing Real P&L
        PnLtotal = unreal_PnL + Real_PnL   '<--totaling

        PnLtotal_USDT = PnLtotal_USDT + (PnLtotal / endprice)   '<--aggregating total
        
        AssetValue_USDT = EndPos * (1 / endprice)    '<--converting to USD
        TotalAssetValue = TotalAssetValue + AssetValue_USDT  '<--aggregating total

        row = row + 1

    Wend

PnLPercent = (PnLtotal_USDT / AssetValue_USDT)*100   '<--calcing profit and loss % 
wsPosition.Cells(7, 6) = PnLtotal_USDT   '<--assigning total
wsPosition.Cells(7, 7) = PnlPercent


End Sub
```

Comment: If startprice = endprice Then
            PriceDelta = 0 
(instead of PriceDelta = endprice) ??

Comment: Could you update your question with sample values in the code? (some lines of setup?)

Comment: code is updated now, still receiving errors

Comment: What kind of errors? (remove () at End Sub ;-)

Comment: With wsPrice (instead of  "With ws.Price") ??

Comment: Dim wsPosition As Range

Comment: Dim wsPrice As Range

Comment: ok updated code(code block above as well), but now receiving error: Compile Error: Wend without While

Comment: Look at my sample! I believe you need to remove one of the with statements and only use the later wend statement!

Comment: Use text compare tools to compare your version with my version!

Comment: Hi - the thing is, "BegPos" and "EndPos" are values located on wsPosition, not wsPrice, isn't the cell command looking at wbPrice, in your code edits?

Comment: ;-) I don't have your data ;-) => get rid of "with wsprice" and reference the cells directly!

Comment: You might want to add some data to your example?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi - added an sample data set of the 2 workbooks of data I'm using for reference as images to give a better idea.

Comment: sorry I didn't get that

Comment: Hi all, code now works, thank you very much @simple-solution for the help!

Comment: Would you please accept my answer?

Comment: @simple-solution this is done

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use "Option Explicit"!
Your "cells(.." commands should reference to wsPrice!

update:
Minor changes to reflect the changes of your code!

Use F8 to go through your programm step by step!

```
Sub PnL2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim PnLUSDT, PnLUSDT_percent As Range
Dim Asset As String
Dim BegPos, EndPos, startprice, endprice, unreal_PnL, Real_PnL As Long
Dim PriceDelta, PnLtotal_USDT, PnLtotal, AssetValue As Long
Dim AssetValue_USDT, TotalAssetValue, PnlPercent As Long
Dim row As Integer
Dim wbPosition As Workbook, wbPrice As Workbook
Dim wsPosition As Range
Dim wsPrice As Range

Set wbPosition = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPosition = wbPosition.Sheets(1).Range("A:G")

'Instead of these two lines

Set wbPrice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Excel Exercise\Excel Exercise 2 of 2.xlsx")
Set wsPrice = wbPrice.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C")

'I use this line and the program works with my data without and error!
'
'        Set wsPrice = Worksheets("table1").Range("A:C")


row = 2               '<--position sheet has heads, starting with data
TotalAssetValue = 0   '<--aggregate of Asset Value in loop
PnLtotal_USDT = 0     '<--aggregrate of Profit & Loss in loop

With wsPrice
    While .Cells(row, 1) <> ""

        Asset = .Cells(row, 1)        '<--security name
       'Debug.Print "Asset: ", Asset
        BegPos = .Cells(row, 2)       '<--start position in ws.Position
        EndPos = .Cells(row, 3)       '<--end position in ws.Positon

'       With wsPrice
           startprice = Application.VLookup(Asset, wsPrice, 2, 0)   '<--start price in ws.Price
           endprice = Application.VLookup(Asset, wsPrice, 3, 0)     '<--end price in ws.Price
   
               If startprice = endprice Then
                   PriceDelta = endprice     'Price change cannot be 0 for calc purposes
               Else
                   PriceDelta = startprice - endprice
               End If
    

        unreal_PnL = EndPos * PriceDelta    '<--calcing unrealized P&L
        Real_PnL = (BegPos - EndPos) * endprice   '<--calcing Real P&L
        PnLtotal = unreal_PnL + Real_PnL   '<--totaling

        PnLtotal_USDT = PnLtotal_USDT + (PnLtotal / endprice)   '<--aggregating total
        
        AssetValue_USDT = EndPos * (1 / endprice)    '<--converting to USD
        TotalAssetValue = TotalAssetValue + AssetValue_USDT  '<--aggregating total

        row = row + 1
'        End With

    Wend

End With

PnlPercent = (PnLtotal_USDT / AssetValue_USDT) * 100 '<--calcing profit and loss %
wsPosition.Cells(7, 6) = PnLtotal_USDT   '<--assigning total
wsPosition.Cells(7, 7) = PnlPercent

End Sub
```